# How can i recreate this orange texture in blender?

Tags: texturing, materials, procedural

[image: oranges]

I have been messing around with noise textures but can't get anything reasonably close to this.

Comment: Sounds like something you could easily recreate using a simple *Voronoi* texture

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question, and add more information and images on how you've set up your material nodes and your current results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with Duarte, I would use a voroni texture plugged into a normal map. Then use the principled shader with SSS set to 1 or 2.

I used a texture in the roughness slot just to break up the shininess.

maybe scale the voroni texture even more than I did to make smaller divits and then bump the strength up a little more. Possibly invert the bump.

[image]

Comment: see also this https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/mastering-lighting, has an interesting .blend maybe